# Как создать новый столбец по результатам группировки и суммирования других столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}])
```

Как можно сгруппировать строки по значению `id` и по значению `b`, например равного `2`, просуммировав значения из столбца `c`, занести их в колонку `d`? То есть, должно получиться так:

```
    pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 6},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 6},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 6},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 6},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 6},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 4},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 4},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 5},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 5},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 5},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 5}])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a["d"] = a["id"].map(a.query("b == 2").groupby("id")["c"].sum())
```

результат:

```
In [268]: a
Out[268]:
    id  b  c  d
0    1  2  2  6
1    1  2  2  6
2    1  4  2  6
3    1  5  2  6
4    1  2  2  6
5    2  3  2  4
6    2  2  2  4
7    2  2  2  4
8    3  2  2  5
9    3  2  2  5
10   3  5  2  5
11   3  2  1  5
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отредактировать ваш код: `a["d"] = a["id"].map(a.query("b == 2").groupby("id")["c"].sum())`, если мне нужно создать столбец, например, `g` также объединяя и группируя, но посчитать количество `c` равное 2. Если делаю так, `a['g'] = a['id'].map(a.query("b == 2").groupby("id")["c"].count())` то просто количество считает, но именно `c == 2` не знаю куда вписать.

Comment: @ChikChirik, предлагаю вам задать новый вопрос с небольшим примером данных и результатом, который вы хотите получить)

Comment: задал) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1255045/362663