# Как найти количество дней до нужной даты?

Tags: python, pandas, дата, время, datetime

Дан df:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 18.12.12},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 14.12.12},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 12.12.12},
                  {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 12.12.12},

                  {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 19.12.12},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 17.12.12},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 12.12.12},
                  {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 12.12.12},

                  {'id': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 17.12.12},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 16.12.12},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 14.12.12},
                  {'id': 3, 'b': 6, 'd': 12.12.12}])
```

Как можно сгруппировать строки по значению `id` и по значению `b`, например равного 2, и по значениям в столбце `d` определить наименьшее прошедшее количество дней до даты в столбце `d`, того же id, но b == 1, занести в столбец `k`?

То есть должно получиться:

```
        pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 18.12.12, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 14.12.12, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 12.12.12, 'k': 3},
                      {'id': 1, 'b': 4, 'd': 12.12.12, 'k': 3},

                      {'id': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 19.12.12, 'k': 2},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 17.12.12, 'k': 2},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12, 'k': 2},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 12.12.12, 'k': 2},
                      {'id': 2, 'b': 3, 'd': 12.12.12, 'k': 2},

                      {'id': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 17.12.12, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 16.12.12, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 15.12.12, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 14.12.12, 'k': 1},
                      {'id': 3, 'b': 6, 'd': 12.12.12, 'k': 1}])
```

Предполагаю, что логика решения этой проблемы такая:

1. мы создаем столбец g по сгруппированным значениям по id и b == 1, добавив в него значения из d
2. далее группируем также по id, но уже по b == 2
3. далее из значения в столбце g вычитаем выше сгруппированные значение в d (дата в столбце g всегда будет позднее)
4. далее выбираем из них минимальное и заносим в столбец k

Возможно есть и более быстрый путь.

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных? Даты в таком виде не работают... Можно задать даты как строки, а потом сконвертмровать их в даты при помощи pd.to_datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
days = ((a.query("b == 1").groupby("id")["d"].min()
         - 
         a.query("b == 2").groupby("id")["d"].max()
        ).dt.days.reset_index(name="k"))
res = a.merge(days, how="left")
```

результат:

```
In [67]: res
Out[67]:
    id  b          d  k
0    1  1 2012-12-18  3
1    1  2 2012-12-15  3
2    1  2 2012-12-14  3
3    1  2 2012-12-12  3
4    1  4 2012-12-12  3
5    2  1 2012-12-19  2
6    2  2 2012-12-17  2
7    2  2 2012-12-15  2
8    2  2 2012-12-12  2
9    2  3 2012-12-12  2
10   3  1 2012-12-17  1
11   3  2 2012-12-16  1
12   3  2 2012-12-15  1
13   3  2 2012-12-14  1
14   3  6 2012-12-12  1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы гений!)) По каким курсам или книгам вы осваивали pandas, можете что-то посоветовать?)

Comment: Начинал изучать по [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html), а после этого заметил, что отвечая на вопросы других людей на SO - постоянно изучаешь что-то новое для себя, с чем еще не сталкивался по роду своей деятельности) Кроме того, когда пишешь ответ - практикуешься и лично для меня это лучший способ что-то выучить и запомнить ;)

Comment: Спасибо за совет)

Comment: добрый день, не знаете как можно решить эту проблему? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1256558/362663. Хотя бы в каком направлении копать или документацию какого метода почитать, даже нет ниодной идеи как можно добавить условие проверки посчитать сумму до появления определенного равенства.

Comment: @ChikChirik, эта задачка за 5 минут не решается. Попробую посмотреть когда у меня будет больше свободного времени...

Comment: здравствуйте, извините на назойливость, у вас еще не появилось больше свободного времени? Похоже кроме вас больше никто не может решить ту задачку..

Answer (score 1):

на самом деле всё очень просто, но этот способ легче чем твой!
#для начала импортируем модуль datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

#далее пишем код!
now = datetime.today() #Это будет наша дата, вводить сюда ничего не нужно
NY = datetime(2022,1,2) #Эта же строка отвечает за дату до которой нам нужно считать, 
в примере новый год
d = NY-now #данная строка считает время до даты которую мы указали в строчке NY
#теперь принтуем!
print("До нового года:", d.days ,"день|дней!")
#на выходе получаем ответ:
До нового года: 294 день|дней!
```

Comment: Ну так мне нужно же все равно вынести в отдельный столбец нужные даты от которых потом вычитать из b == 1 каждого id, не пойму как это все в одно собрать

Comment: Вы, вероятно, не поняли сути вопроса. Речь идёт про векторизованное решение датафрейма pandas. А вы тут пример из начального курса по питону приводите.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не очень нравится это решения ввиду отсутствия изящества, но, тем не менее:

```
df["k"] =df[df["b"]==1].groupby("id")["d"].transform("first")
df["k"] = df["k"].fillna(method="ffill").dt.day - df["d"].dt.day
df["k"] = df.groupby("id")["k"].transform(lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].min())
```

df:

```
    id  b          d  k
0    1  1 2012-12-18  3
1    1  2 2012-12-15  3
2    1  2 2012-12-14  3
3    1  2 2012-12-12  3
4    1  4 2012-12-12  3
5    2  1 2012-12-19  2
6    2  2 2012-12-17  2
7    2  2 2012-12-15  2
8    2  2 2012-12-12  2
9    2  3 2012-12-12  2
10   3  1 2012-12-17  1
11   3  2 2012-12-16  1
12   3  2 2012-12-15  1
13   3  2 2012-12-14  1
14   3  6 2012-12-12  1
```