# Как создать новый столбец, суммировав значения из первого столбца по условию из второго?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Прошу не кидаться камнями, я - только учусь)
Есть датафрейм на основе csv, в который нужно добавить столбец с суммой чека, т.е. суммировать все значения `sum` по `id`, где `sum` - это стоимость товара, а `id` - идентификатор товара. Грубо говоря: как создать столбец, в котором суммировать значения из столбца `sum`, если `id` одинаковый?

| id | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 235578624 | 118,46 |
| 235639412 | 75,28 |
| 235716906 | 195 |
| 235801993 | 57,84 |
| 235801993 | 300,43 |

Comment: Не понятно с чем вы хотите суммировать стоимость товара. Вы хотите весь столбец суммировать? Или вам нужно сумму каждого товара с чем-то сложить? sum + ? = profit!!!!!

Comment: Начните с `df.groupby('id')['sum'].sum()`, потом это можно будет соединить через `join`, например.

Comment: Я хочу вывести в новом столбце суммированное значение столбца `sum`, если у них одинаковое значение `id`. Если разное значение `id`, то не суммировать - не понимаю как это можно сделать((

Comment: А я не понимаю как у вас в таблице может быть два(и более) одинаковых id =). Возможно вы используете связи таблиц (один-ко-многим, многие-ко-многим) в таком случае вам просто нужно получить данные из таблицы, поместить их в "массив в массиве" и в каждом вложенном массиве проверять первый элемент(который по сути id). В случае нахождения массивов в которых первые элементы одинаковые - сложить их вторые элементы которые являются "sum".

Comment: @Old_Lamer лучше не советовать ничего, чем советовать такое. у человека в вопросе стоят метки pandas. наверняка, не зря, как вы считаете?

Comment: @strawdog Понятия не имею что такое pandas. Я просто предложил вариант на чистом python. Знаю что решение вообще не идеальное, но работать будет))

Comment: @Voort Ну я же вам написал прямо код гроупбай. Вы даже не попробовали?

Comment: @CrazyElf, да я попробовал, но не понял как встроить получившиеся значения в отдельный столбец. Прошу прощения, делаю первые робкие шаги в анализе: я думаю что мне надо пойти примерно по такому пути? (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254692)

Comment: @Voort Нет, я опять же уже упомянул, что лучше использовать https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html по столбцу `id`

Comment: Либо, как вариант, сделать из результата `groupby` словарь и через `map` применить его к столбцу `id`. Вариантов много можно придумать.

Comment: @CrazyElf поделитесь пожалуйста любым решением, бьюсь над задачей уже уже 4-ый день и в голове уже просто пляшут тараканы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ладно, вот вам рабочий пример, хотя я все подсказки давал, можно было разобраться:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
id  sum
235578624   118,46
235639412   75,28
235716906   195
235801993   57,84
235801993   300,43"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\t', decimal=',')

# ниже собственно код группировки и добавления столбца
sumsum = df.groupby('id')['sum'].sum().to_dict()
df['sumsum'] = df['id'].map(sumsum)
df
```

| index | id | sum | sumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 235578624 | 118.46 | 118.46 |
| 1 | 235639412 | 75.28 | 75.28 |
| 2 | 235716906 | 195.0 | 195.0 |
| 3 | 235801993 | 57.84 | 358.27 |
| 4 | 235801993 | 300.43 | 358.27 |

Comment: Спасибо! Особенно спасибо за помощь глупому падавану)