# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' как избежать этой проблемы при определении выбросов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

При определении выбросов в датафрейме столкнулся с данной ошибкой. Создал новый столбец используя код, пример файла в вопросе [Как создать новый столбец, суммировав значения из первого столбца по условию из второго?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1530150/):

```
    sum_id = df.groupby('order_id')['amount'].sum().to_dict()
    df['sum_id'] = df['order_id'].map(sum_id)
```

Затем попытался определить выбросы в новом столбце:

```
    Q1 =  df['sum_id'].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df['sum_id'].quantile(0.75)
    df_IQR = df[(df['sum_id'] > (Q1-1.5*IQR)) & (df['sum_id'] < (Q3+1.5*IQR))]
    df_IQR.boxplot(column="sum_id")`
```

но вышла ошибка. Попытался исправить её с помощью:

```
    a = map(float, input().split())
    a = ['sum_id']
    number = []
    or item in a:
    number.append(float(item))
```

Также попытался использовать методы `str.strip()`, `re.findall()`, `str.replace()`, однако каждый раз выходят разного типа ошибки.

Comment: Первым делом глазами надо данные смотреть. Что у вас в `sum_id` получилось - смотрели? Где строка подсчёта `IQR`, что у вас там? Скорее всего ошибка вообще в той строке, где `IQR` считается. Ну и последний блок кода совсем какой-то бред, вы там `a` переприсваиваете и получается список из одной строки.